# Array inside array (input multiple form data and select)

Tags: php, html

My code is

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="batch_code[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="12" name="qty[]"/></td>
<td>
<select id="asset_id" class="asset_id" name="asset_id[][]" multiple="multiple">
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 1</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 2</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="batch_code[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="12" name="qty[]"/></td>
<td>
<select id="asset_id" class="asset_id" name="asset_id[][]" multiple="multiple">
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 1</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 2</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get array inside array. but if i get print_r() of this asset_id. it result was 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Asset Id 1
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Asset Id 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Asset Id 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Asset Id 3
    )
```

)

but what i want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Asset Id 1
            [1] => Asset Id 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Asset Id 1
            [1] => Asset Id 3

        )
)
```

i was running this code with one square bracket "name="asset_id[]"" but it result was
Array
(

```
[0] => Asset Id 1
[1] => Asset Id 2
[2] => Asset Id 1
[3] => Asset Id 3
```

)

please help me..

Comment: You need answers? Format your question, proof read well, then post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="batch_code[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="12" name="qty[]"/></td>
<td>
<select id="asset_id" class="asset_id" name="asset_id[0][]" multiple="multiple">
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 1</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 2</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="batch_code[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="12" name="qty[]"/></td>
<td>
<select id="asset_id" class="asset_id" name="asset_id[1][]" multiple="multiple">
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 1</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 2</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

**Update:**
I have tried this out of curiosity, and the results are as required:

```
  ["asset_id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Asset Id 1"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "Asset Id 2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Asset Id 1"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "Asset Id 3"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name="assed_id[1][]"
```

that will help

Answer (score 0):

Why Using Two dimension Array. Use asset_id[] instead of asset_id[][]

Correct code

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="batch_code[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="12" name="qty[]"/></td>
<td>
<select id="asset_id" class="asset_id" name="asset_id[]" multiple="multiple">
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 1</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 2</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="batch_code[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="12" name="qty[]"/></td>
<td>
<select id="asset_id" class="asset_id" name="asset_id[]" multiple="multiple">
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 1</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 2</option> 
<option class="dropdownlist">Asset Id 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```